# javascript/jquery select all child elements inside a parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of child elements that are uniquely identified within a parent div.  I want to know if there's a way in jQuery (or javascript) to capture all of them?  The number of children in the parent div is arbitrary, meaning it could be any number for each div.  For example:

```
<div class="parent1">
   <span class="child1">some text here</span>
   <span class="child2">some other text</span>
   ...
   <span class="child49">yet more text</span>
   <span class="something_else">other text i don't want to select</span>
</div>
<div class="parent2">
   <span class="child1">some text</span>
   <span class="child2">some text</span>
   ...
   <span class="child120">some text</span>
</div>
```

So considering the above example, how do I get ALL the children (`.child1` through `.child49`) within the class `parent1`?

I know that doing the following will work in jQuery (using multiple selector):

```
$(".child1, .child2, ..., .child49").css("background","red");
```

But is there a better way?  I won't always know how many children are in each parent.

EDIT: also, I might have other children in the parent with a different class name that I DO NOT want to select; I specifically want to select all the "child*" classes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('.parent1 span[class^="child"]')
```

will select all the `span`s that start with the class `child` under the class `.parent1`.

If you want all the `span.childX` under all `parentX` then use:

```
$('div[class^="parent"] span[class^="child"]')
```

This is using a [`CSS3 attribute selector`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) which jQuery have implemented (and extended in some cases). From the documentation:

`E[foo^="bar"]` an E element whose `"foo"` attribute value begins exactly with the string `"bar"`

Comment: This only selects the SPANs, is there a way to select ALL child elements?

Comment: @GregL Yes this answers the question that was asked where _child_ referred to the class rather than the element relationship. Your question is different and should be asked separately. That said, if you just want _all_ children under a specific element you can use the CSS Universal selector [`*`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#universal-selector) and child combinator [`>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators) for example `$('div > *')` would select all direct children of a `<div>`

Answer (score 2):

These codes gets all child in div.parent1 and div.parent2

```
$('[class^="parent"] span').css({ });
$('[class^="parent"]').children().css({ });
```

Thess codes gets onli the children for parent 1

```
$('.parent1 span').css...
$('.parent1').children().css...
```

Comment: Thanks, what if I have other spans inside the parent div that i do not want to select; such as a span that is not labeled as "child" but has a different class like "something_else", i don't want it to select that span.

Comment: I don't know if I understand you but try this: $('.parent1 span:not(.something_else)')... i think.

Answer (score 1):

use `.children` along with `.filter`, if number of children are not certain then label all childs which you want to manipulate of parent1 as child1

```
 $(".parent1").children().filter(".child1").css({color:'Red'});
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8hUqV/1/

[`jquery children`](http://api.jquery.com/children/)